# Are forged signatures on company documents illegal?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, tax-law, fraud, forgery

Are forged signatures illegal on company documents even if they're forged by the director of the company?

Example: I looked over some documents for a small company founded by three persons, I believe that the two of the three signatures used during the documentation to found the company were written by the same person. The false signatures also seem to be used in six different companies that all seem to start up then dissolve within months. These signatures were also used for tax exemption in the UK.

I don't know if it's illegal since I believe he is the owner of said company that is writing all three signatures.

Answer (score 5):

I was told that when you sign something in the UK, then it is *your* signature, no matter what name you are using. So if *you* sign a contract with *my name*, then it's your signature and you are bound by the contract.

Things might be invalid because you signed and not me. For example, if you sign a contract selling my car in my name, then that contract is not valid. If some document needs signatures of two witnesses, and you sign with your name, then with my name, then there are no two signatures.

As far as I know, signing under a false name is not in itself criminal, but might very well be supporting fraud, for example, and might therefore be illegal. The contract for the sale of my car, signed by you using my name, would very likely be part of fraud and therefore criminal.